# finding values of $a$ for which the limit exists

Tags: calculus, functions, limits

I've been banging my head all day long over this question, would apprecate some help :)

> $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-1} - \frac{a}{x^3-1},\qquad a\in\mathbb{R}.$$
>   For which values of $a$ does $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f( x)$ exist?

Also it was requested to use only the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$, and then subtract the two fractions by finding the least common denominator.

Answer (score 2):

Both denominators are $0$ when $x=1$; therefore $(x-1)$ is a factor of both.  So factor them, then find the common denominator:
$$
\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{x^2-1} - \frac{a}{x^3-1} = \frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)} - \frac{a}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)} \\  \\
& = \frac{x^2+x+1}{(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)} - \frac{a(x+1)}{(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)}
\end{align}
$$
The limit can exist only if the numerator
$$
x^2+x+1 - a(x+1)
$$
is $0$ when $x=1$.  And it is equal to $3-2a$ when $x=1$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: yeah I understand the idea, thanks for the help :)